# Java Threads are not running on separate objects

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, animation

I am working on a school project that involves generating two separate Swing Canvas objects which animate Breadth/Depth-First Search Algorithms on cloned copies of a Matrix/Grid Data Structure I have designed.

I have created a few classes that help translate the Matrix/Grid into graphics, which are combined in a SearchAnimation class that acts a ViewController for managing the animations. In the image below, they appear on the right (not in the yellow background area). Each SearchAnimation object includes a JLabel, Canvas, and White Background.

Below is a screenshot of the layout:
[image]

The JFrame contains two instances of the SearchAnimation Class in the Application Controller Class (ICL.java). These animations must run concurrently. I have created separate Threads for each animation, passing it separate SearchAnimation objects:

```
public void setupDepthFirstPanel() {
            // Create a new GridGraphic Panel
            //canvasDepthFirst = new GridPanel(null, DEPTH_FIRST_LABEL);
            mDepthAnimation = new SearchAnimation(null, SearchAnimationType.DEPTH_FIRST_ANIMATION);
            mDepthThread = new Thread(mDepthAnimation, "Depth Thread");
        }

        public void setupBreadthFirstPanel() {
            // Create a new GridGraphic Panel
            //canvasBreadthFirst = new GridPanel(null, BREADTH_FIRST_LABEL);
            mBreadthAnimation = new SearchAnimation(null, SearchAnimationType.BREADTH_FIRST_ANIMATION);
            mBreadthThread = new Thread(mBreadthAnimation, "Breadth Thread");
        }
```

I start the Threads in the ActionListener class that responds to the Click Event of the button that labeled "Label Components":

```
if ( source == labelComponents ) {
            if (DEBUG && DEBUG_CLICK_LISTENER) System.out.println("\"Label Components\" Button Clicked!");
            /*This is where the call for the labelBreadth and labelDepth of the
            ICLLogic class is going to occur*/

            // Run Animation
            // Set Up Threads
            System.out.println("ICL.ActionPerformed - Current Thread: " + Thread.currentThread());
            //mBreadthThread = new Thread(mBreadthAnimation, "Breadth Animation");
            //mDepthThread = new Thread(mDepthAnimation, "Depth Animation");

            // Start Threads
            mBreadthThread.start();
            mDepthThread.start();
        }
```

When the program runs and the "Label Components" button is clicked, only one of the graphics starts animating, but it seems as though both SearchAnimation Threads are running within a single JPanel/Canvas since the animation does not follow the logic of either algorithm.

Here is the implementation of the Runnable Interface within SearchAnimation:

```
// THREAD METHODS
    /** Implementation of the Runnable interface for Multithreading of the
     *  SearchAnimation Class, which allows multiple SearchAnimations to run Concurrently.
     *  In this case, the Breadth & Depth-First SearchAnimations
     * 
     */
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread Started - " + mAnimationType.toString());

        // Run the Animation
        step();

    }
```

Which eventually calls determineSearchType() that switches on an Enum to pick the appropriate Algorithm:

```
public void determineSearchType(Pixel p) {
    // Animate a single pixel movement, step depends on AnimationType
    if (DEBUG && DEBUG_STEP_NEXT_PIXEL) { System.out.println("Determining Animation Type..."); }
    switch (mAnimationType) {

        case BREADTH_FIRST_ANIMATION:
            if (DEBUG && DEBUG_STEP_NEXT_PIXEL) { System.out.println("Animation Type: Breadth-First"); }
            // Begin Breadth-First Search
            stepBreadthSearch(p);
            break;

        case DEPTH_FIRST_ANIMATION:
            if (DEBUG && DEBUG_STEP_NEXT_PIXEL) { System.out.println("Animation Type: Depth-First"); }
            // Begin Depth-First Search
            stepDepthSearch(p);
            //simpleDepthSearch(mCurrentPixel);
            break;  
    }
}
```

When I alternate commenting them out, each Thread/Animation executes in its own JPanel/Canvas graphic and produces the expected results. I am pretty new to threading and I'm sure someone has an easy solution. Any ideas at how I can fix the issue that the animations won't animate simultaneously?

Comment: Sadly, Swing is absolutely **not** threadsafe. You **absolutely** cannot access Swing objects from multiple threads. This **will** result is unpredictable behaviour. All and any interactions with Swing objects **must** happen on the EDT.

Comment: Even if they are separate instances that have separate references and property values? The class extends these swing objects.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Swing must happen on the EDT. Full stop. You need to use [Swing workers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) to carry out background tasks.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess I'll have to email my teach and ask if this really was his intent. The project is more about the algorithms than Threading.

Comment: @Matt, Yes, even if you have multiple threads. The Swing API has one, single head which is responsible for processing the one, single Event Queue. So all updates to the ui must be synced with this thread. Some methods like repaint, because of the way they work, add events to the event queue, but the EDT is still processing them. Most GUIs work this way

Comment: @matt You can still do animation, you just need to keep the state management from the ui, let the ui update to the state as required (from within the context of the EDT), you can use a SwingWorker or Swing Timer depending on your needs

Comment: It sounds like you also may mistakenly have two views to the same data structure.

Comment: The data structure is a generic class Grid<T>, which is a property of the SearchAnimation class. Each instance has a reference to a separate copy/clone of a Grid<T> object - using super.toString() logs different references.

Answer (score -1):

option1 :

to give another Thread chance to be executed. at the end of thread code, try [yield()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield()) and see if you have some luck

```
Thread.currentThread().yield();
```

option2 :

add flag in your thread, to pause and continue the thread. the idea is

after thread 1 finish the step
 - pause thread 1 - then start thread 2 - after thread 2 finish the step
 - pause thread 2 - and continue thread 1 again.